# What is the reason for a shaded dummy module?

Tags: maven, hadoop, parquet

During the investigation of some vulnerabilities in our maven project I discovered that the parquet-hadoop dependency has a dependency on the parquet-jackson module which is a dummy module to shade jackson artifacts. (https://apache.googlesource.com/parquet-mr/+/refs/heads/fix_concurency_problem/parquet-jackson/)

The problem in this case was that the shaded jackson version was an outdated one with vulnerabilities which showed up in the Jfrog vulnerability scan but the dependecy tree in intellij does not show the vulnerable module. It shows the parquet-jackons module which has a different version then the shaded jackson version it includes. The shaded module does not appear in the tree.

What is the reason for this parquet-jackson dummy module and why did they not just  use directly the desired jackson version as dependency?

This makes it more difficult to find vulnerable modules in a project.
Or is there a way to also show shaded modules in the dependency tree in intellij or with the maven cli?

**Edit:**

In the parquet-jackson documentation linked above it is mentioned that

> Parquet “shades” its copy of Jackson to prevent any side-effect.

But what side-effect is this and what is the benefit of this copy module over using the original module right away?

Comment: I think your first question is answered in the link you provided. And for the second question, the answer is probably no. I have never heard of such a detection tool.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Thanks for answering the second question. For the first question they indeed give an explenation but I still don't understand. I added an edit to the question. Maybe you could ellaborate?

Comment: This is the old problem of "you can have only one version of a dependency". So if any other dependency in your project uses a certain version of jackson, this version would also be used for Parquet and may break their code.

Comment: But this is the task of the dependency management tool like maven. If a package defines which exact version of a dependency it needs to work correctly the management tool should make sure this version is used in the project or throw an error if their is a conflict of versions.

Comment: Standard Maven does not work that way. You can use the maven enforcer plugin to break the build if different transitive versions are conflicting.